# ssh proxyjump into tailscale network from outside network

Tags: ssh, tailscale

Is it possible to proxyjump into the tailscale network from outside the network, such as from the local library or university computer? Something like:

```
ssh -J user@bastion user@tailscale-ip
```

Or:

```
ssh -A -t user@bastion ssh -A -t user@tailscale-ip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your bastion is connected to the tailnet, both work as expected because in both cases the port forward is done on the jump host which has tailnet routes. Port-forwarding would work as well if you were trying to forward a port to a tailnet node instead of SSH. Depending on your circumstances, it may be easier to just use [Tailscale SSH](https://tailscale.com/tailscale-ssh) and open a shell via the admin web interface.

Comment: Got it; thanks for the help! As a side note, do you know why my question was closed as off-topic? There seem to be quite a few Tailscale questions here, if I remember correctly.

Comment: I guess it rubbed a few moderators the wrong way and they thought it would be better fit on ServerFault? I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Hmm... That's fair, I guess. Ah, well. Thanks anyway!